# replace() Method don't replace anything

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, str-replace

In `cup[number][9]` is:

```
 //ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&amp;OneJS=1&amp;Operation=GetAdHtml&amp;MarketPlace=US&amp;source=ac&amp;ref=tf_til&amp;ad_type=product_link&amp;tracking_id=nameid-20&amp;marketplace=amazon®ion=US&amp;placement=B004BCXAM8&amp;asins=B004BCXAM8&amp;linkId=SK5UG2J5CK4WNOKE&amp;show_border=true&amp;link_opens_in_new_window=true
```

This is my code:

```
var str   = cup[number][9];
str=str.replace('amazon®ion','amazon&region');
```

`amazon®ion` is not replaced. What is wrong with this code?

update:

Solved with:

```
var str = escape(cup[number][9]);
str=str.replace('amazon%AEion','amazon%26ampregion'); 
str=unescape(str);str=str.replace('ampregion','region');
```

Comment: Probably this sign -> ®

Comment: It works in my browser's console (Chrome 42), don't see what's wrong

Comment: Working for me as well (also Chrome). Are you checking `str` or `cup[number][9]` for the value after the `replace()`? Only `str` is being updated.

Comment: If I use var str   = "//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&amp;OneJS=1&amp;Operation=GetAdHtml&amp;MarketPlace=US&amp;source=ac&amp;ref=tf_til&amp;ad_type=product_link&amp;tracking_id=nameid-20&amp;marketplace=amazon®ion=US&amp;placement=B004BCXAM8&amp;asins=B004BCXAM8&amp;linkId=SK5UG2J5CK4WNOKE&amp;show_border=true&amp;link_opens_in_new_window=true" amazon®ion is replaced. If str = cup[number][9] amazon®ion is not replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

```
var str   = encodeURI(cup[number][9]);
str = decodeURI( str.replace( encodeURI('amazon®ion'), encodeURI('amazon&amp;region') );
```

**encodeURI() & decodeURI()**

- Since it's a url, this is the favorable function
- With the use of `encodeURI('amazon®ion')` you don't have to seccond guess the encoded character(s)
- `&` in `amazon&region` needs to be in the form of `&amp;`, like so: `amazon&amp;region`
- use `decodeURI()` to use the new URI

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cbsL9ed7/2/

---

### Want an even better and more flexible solution?

Why not make it a function then?

```
function updateURI(uri, oldValue, newValue) {
    var str = encodeURI( uri );
    str = decodeURI( str.replace( encodeURI(oldValue), encodeURI(newValue) ) );
    return str;
}


var newURI = updateURI(cup[number][9], 'amazon®ion', 'amazon&amp;region');
document.write( newURI )
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cbsL9ed7/4/

Comment: This is the result: //ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q%3FServiceVersion%3D20070822%26amp%3BOneJS%3D1%26amp%3BOperation%3DGetAdHtml%26amp%3BMarketPlace%3DUS%26amp%3Bsource%3Dac%26amp%3Bref%3Dtf_til%26amp%3Bad_type%3Dproduct_link%26amp%3Btracking_id%3Dnameid-20%26amp%3Bmarketplace%3Damazon%AEion%3DUS%26amp%3Bplacement%3DB004BCXAM8%26amp%3Basins%3DB004BCXAM8%26amp%3BlinkId%3DSK5UG2J5CK4WNOKE%26amp%3Bshow_border%3Dtrue%26amp%3Blink_opens_in_new_window%3Dtrue

Comment: @user3944364 I updated my answer, the proper escaped form of `&` is `%26` and the escaped form of `®` is `%AE`

Comment: the link is broken https://jsfiddle.net/u2qufd0e/ is not a product in first iframe

Comment: @user3944364 What do you mean? -They show up well here

Comment: the second iframe is an example of how need to be. there need to be a product in the first iframe https://jsfiddle.net/u2qufd0e/

Comment: @user3944364 I updated the answer. Did you notice the changes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75441/discussion-between-omar-and-user3944364).

Comment: same amazon®ion in the link. But I changed your code into this and I get a good result: str=str.replace('amazon%AEion','amazon%26ampregion');
str=unescape(str);str=str.replace('ampregion','region'); Thanks

Comment: `str=str.replace('amazon%AEion','amazon%26ampregion'); str=unescape(str);str=str.replace('ampregion','region');`

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are looking at `cup[number][9]` and seeing that it hasn't changed. That's because you're only modifying the value of the `str` variable, not `cup[number][9]`.

Since you're reassigning `str` to a brand new string, it does not affect the object that `str` used to be pointing to.

It's a concept you have to be careful with when you're dealing with object-oriented code. If you have two variables which point to the same object, *reassigning* one of the variables will not reassign the other.

**EDIT**

Here's some code. Let's cut out some of the distracting stuff in that string, and just do the following:

```
var number = 0;
var cup = [];
cup[number] = [];
cup[number][9] = "marketplace=amazon®ion";
var str = cup[number][9];
str=str.replace('amazon®ion','amazon&region');

console.log(cup[number][9]);
console.log(str);
```

This will give you the following output:

```
marketplace=amazon®ion
marketplace=amazon&region
```

If you're looking at `cup[number][9]`, you'll see the original string. If you look at `str`, you'll see the new string, because `str` was the only thing that was given a new value.

If you want to modify the value in the array, you'll have to reassign that directly, and you can skip the whole `str` part:

```
cup[number][9] = cup[number][9].replace('amazon®ion','amazon&region');
console.log(cup[number][9]);
```

Now it will have your new value.

Comment: *"It's a concept you have to be careful with when you're dealing with object-oriented code."* This behavior is not specific to OOP.

Comment: @FelixKling True. I guess my point is there is a huge difference between `var a = {}; var b = a; a.X = 34;`, which I would consider an OOP concept, and `var a = 34; var b = a; a = 42;`.

Comment: Oh, sure. I'm just saying that assigning a value to a variable usually doesn't update another variable, no matter whether OO or not. But I think I understand your point better now (it is in contrast to mutating objects).

Comment: @FelixKling I use str to print the result. Mabe because cup[number][9] is an array, replace() method can't see the data?

Comment: I don't know enough about how JS and Chrome handle encoding, but could this be a charset issue, @JoeEnos? Could explain why it works when he pastes the value into a string literal, but not when he retrieves it from what (I presume) is from another non-literal source.

Comment: @joe-enos Look at the code!!! He's assigning the value of the array INTO `var str` and using `var str` to modify the string. You need to change your answer

Comment: @user3944364 and Chris and Omar, see my edit, showing the issue in more detail, assuming I understand the original question. This answer does not deal with the URL encoding, since that's a totally different issue, and may still be something you have to think about, depending on what you're doing with that string.

Comment: @JoeEnos str contain marketplace=amazon®ion. I solved with this code: var str   = escape(cup[number][9]);str=str.replace('amazon%AEion','amazon%26ampregion'); str=unescape(str);str=str.replace('ampregion','region');

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the URL encoded syntax when replacing this:

```
str=str.replace('amazon®ion','amazon&amp;region');
```

Here is a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sqqfrgb0/1/

Even though the valid syntax for this is `&reg;`  it is still recognizing it as an `®` so that is why you need to replace with `&amp;` instead of `&`